# Bootstrap navbar hamburger menu not collapsing

Tags: html, web, bootstrap-4, navbar, hamburger-menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark shadow fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand fw-bold logo" href="#">Logo</a>
            <!-- navbar button -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" role="button"></span>
          </button>
          <!-- end navbar button -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
                <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <a class="nav-link active text-end" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-end" href="#about">About Me</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-end" href="#movie">Movie</a>
                    <a class="nav-link text-end" href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I dont really understand what is wrong the code, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're using data attributes for Bootstrap 5. Be sure to follow the [correct documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/navbar/).